# What happens to executing bytecode when pausing an android activity?

Tags: android

I have some code that runs when I start an android activity. I'll read from shared preference and from a web server if required. Some of this will happen on the main thread, obviously server requests are in an AsyncTask.

Now what I am wondering is what happens if, for example the app is paused. Does the byte code stop wherever the program counter is or wait for whatever is happening on the main loop to finish and then call onPause.

Further, I am concerned about include what will happen to a callback on receiving data from a network. Can the callback occur after resumption from pause or will it always be lost? As I understand it the thread reading from the network could still run whilst the activity was paused.

Answer (score 5):

Ok well I have done some experimentation and had a glance at the Android source for an Activity and I am a bit clearer now.

Things that i have found:

1. onPause, onResume, onStart, onCreate etc all run inside the same thread (by printing `Thread.currentThread.getId()`) which is the main event thread, and this single event thread is used for all activities (unless you allocated a new process in the manifest). This isn't wholly unexpected but I did wonder if onPause, for example, might live in a system started thread used to stop the activity.
2. If you have an infinite while in your code (say in onResume or in code executed as a result of a button press) then onPause and the rest will not ever be executed. Further, that loop will continue to execute as can be seen, for example, by printing to the log every second. If you were going to the home screen (or anything else that should generate onPause and even onStop) these prints will still occur and the loop continues despite the app being invisible. You will still go to the home screen. And you can if you want then go back into your app which will still be stuck in its loop. Therefore, when the documentation talks about the action of pausing or stopping an activity, clearly this does not stop application execution wherever it is, or generate a runtime exception in the main thread (before calling onPause) or anything else. Pausing and killing activities is not at all related to the concepts in linux processes it seems.
3. If I have a slow web request running in an AsyncTask, that asynctask code will run in a different thread, as you would expect. If the activity that started the task gets paused before the task finished its work, and onPause, onStop are called as normal, then when the asynctask finishes it's callback (defined in the Activity), onPostExecute will still get called and executed, in the main gUI thread. This is despite the fact that the "Activity" has stopped cleanly.

What I conclude from this is that all onStop and onStart, etc are simply events in the main event loop, just like any other, that must wait their turn to be called in the main thread. They are not anything special, are not instantly executed or anything like that and can be blocked by anything else in the loop.

Further, the concept of an Activity is really just a GUI thing, whereby if an Activity is stopped there is no screen or buttons to interact with or display things on. However, this does not have a bearing on the underlying process which will continue to be active and can print, or respond to callbacks etc. The JVM continues and all its classes continue to exist and the process continues to execute. Obviously it should be doing nothing though if not receiving any events or interaction from the GUI and having received onPause. If it does hog resources of any kind, then this process can of course be shut down - which is why you should implement the lifecycle callbacks.

As an aside we can see in Activity.java that pausing happens by a call to

```
final void performPause() {
        mFragments.dispatchPause();
        mCalled = false;
        onPause();
        mResumed = false;
```

then to

```
protected void onPause() {
        if (DEBUG_LIFECYCLE) Slog.v(TAG, "onPause " + this);
        getApplication().dispatchActivityPaused(this);
        mCalled = true;
    }
```

which shows that as expected from the testing, pausing is really just dispatching another event to the main loop.

I presume the mCalled variable has two uses - one to ensure that the super() version was called in your Activity derived class, the other being for the system to check that it was called before destroying a process where resources are needed.

Given how this works, if onPause is being slow, or has been blocked by something else in the even loop, it can be the case that your process gets killed before onPause has completed.

Obviously some of this may be obvious to some people. But I found the documentation quite confusing. I was unable to reason about the states my code could get into without understanding what the concepts of running, paused etc actually meant in terms of code ordering as I thought pausing might mean runtime exceptions on whatever the gui thread was doing.

If I have totally misunderstood this and got the wrong idea please do let me know! I have only been using Android 2.5 weeks and it's quite possible I am quite confused!